# How to remove Links in Webpart

Tags: web-part

I am trying to build a simple community site with web parts.

I am trying to remove some links in some web parts eg link for +new topic for discussion list or some items in the community tools (because we don't need them) and trying to make the page “clean”

Even though I have SharePoint Designer, I cannot seem to know where those links are in the webparts “WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart”

Unfortunately I have no knowledge of coding or CSS so its been hard to find a simple answer

Too bad WYSIWYG is not working in SharePoint Designer 2013 so I have no idea how to remove these URLs

Like, how do I remove links like “Assign Badges to members” in web parts

Please, some advice?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer

Using Content Editor and pasting

```
<style>
    #forum1-NewPostLink{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```